# React won't respond to any request

Tags: reactjs, express

I am working on an app where I am making a request and trying to send my data back to react via fetch.

So far here's my router file:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('I got here before request..... >>>>>>>>>');   
  request(`https://rest.coinapi.io//v1/exchangerate/BTC?apikey=${API}`, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log('I got here..... >>>>>>>>>');   
    if(error){
      console.log('error >>>>>>', error);
    }
    console.log(response.body);
  });
});
```

And i included to main server,js

```
// include routes
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening to port 3000...');
});
```

And then finally I sent my data to react:

```
class MainApp extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getInitial();
  }

  getInitial() {
    fetch('/')
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ 
      data: data.rates
    }))
    .then(() => console.log('this is is a state >>>>+++', this.state))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>HELLO WORLD FROM REACT CLIENT FRONTEND! PP</h1>
        <p>{this.state.data}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

For some reason I am not getting any console.log on my express when i run my code and I am getting this error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Any idea what am doing wrong why I can't change the state? and why the request doesn't run?

Comment: Your response is `html` that's why you got the error. make sure the url for the api is correct.

Comment: Is babel there at your server ? I mean in your express code ?

Comment: I set up babel as my loader on webpack

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't React. The data is in JSON form, which has bunch of keys, value inside. You need to use a map function to render the {this.state.data}. You can not call a entire JSON object like that. You have to dig deep in the JSON Object and get whatever you need.

Let's assume you have the following JSON data.

```
{
  "crypto": {
    "BTC": {
      "name": "bitcoin",
      "current_price": "$6592.3"
    }
  }
}
```

you can't just say {this.state.data}. In this case you probably will do something like this {this.state.data.crypto.BTC.name} to get the name of the BTC-crypto symbol. Using the map function you can get name and prices of all the crypto symbol assuming there are more.

Comment: using this kind of data: https://jsfiddle.net/rzfzwvc9/ i set up my setState to data: data.rates and then when i tried to output them i put <p>{this.state.data.rate}</p> but in the end I got an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rate' of null

Comment: You data looks like it's JSON object inside which there's an array. 
`{
 asset_id_base: "BTC",
 rates: [
 {
 time: "2018-04-13T12:37:03.3284410Z",
 asset_id_quote: "1ST",
 rate: 39401.10323089046
 }]
}`

In this case, you have to get inside the JSON, then the array. {this.state.data.rates[0].rate}. Use a loop to get all the rate, replace 0 with the correct Index.

Comment: I even tried to access it like an array just like what you said above but the same thing came up.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rzfzwvc9/12/

Check this link, I added some .js code all the way at the end. Remember this React is basic JavaScript with some changes. The logic's are the same in react and javascript.

Answer (score 1):

actually your code on server does not send any response. When you are using console.log on server - you will see that messages in terminal, where you execute command "nodejs app.js" or some other to start server. To send response, depending on node framework, you are using, you should do something like this:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    ...
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(SOME_JSON);
});
```

Also as i see, your server is listening port 3000, but fetch sends request not there

Comment: Can you see in log (terminal) what exactly you send? Can you show it?

Comment: Same thing. SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0    And also my express console.log doesnt work either,

Comment: I recommend you to remove any logic from your server and get code from here https://medium.com/@adnanrahic/hello-world-app-with-node-js-and-express-c1eb7cfa8a30

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});

then convert your response to JSON. And then step by step add your logic

Comment: Also as i see, your server is listening port 3000, but fetch sends request not there

Comment: fetch is on my react file. that where I am fetching the data from express request and then flowing my data to react state..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168938/discussion-between-tony-beatty-and-sasha-kos).